# I can't make the sqljdbc work with AD username/password

Tags: java, jdbc, database-connection, connection-string, mssql-jdbc

I need to connect to High Availability (HA) / Desaster Recovery (DR), also known as HADR, enabled SQL server 2012 using AD account from Java on Linux.

- `integratedSecurity` is not an option since it runs on Linux
- I can not use the jTDS JDBC driver since it does not support HADR cluster (no support for `multiSubnetFailover=true`)

jTDS actually works with username, password and domain connection string parameters, but times out 25% of the time.

So it seems I'm stuck with MS SQL JDBC driver but I can't make it work with just the username/password credentials, as I'm trying to solve this without Kerberos.

It must be possible to do it (in theory), since jTDS can actually do it!

I found that driver version 6.0 has property [`authentication=ActiveDirectoryPassword`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378988(v=sql.110).aspx) so it looked very promising, but a SQL connection string like

```
jdbc:sqlserver://server:port;database=DB;authentication=ActiveDirectoryPassword;username=name;password=PASSWORD
```

even trying with `DOMAIN\username` for username or user property, isn't working.

The docs says its for

> using an Azure AD principal name and password

but it would just make my life so much easier.

The error I get is

> Login failed for user ''

and shows empty user, but stepping through the decompiled code I can see the username and password values are being loaded into variables.

Any solution for this? I take any AD username/password connection to HADR SQL server 2012 that is pure JAVA.

Comment: I'm curious to know if you found a solution, I believe this may be impossible until jTDS supports HADR.

Comment: It seem impossible, what jTDS is using is LDAP auth that MS SQL driver does not support that. Since MS SQL is now open source someone could potentially implement that

Comment: There is a 10 year old [connect case](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/275681/sql-jdbc-integrated-security-with-domain-account-from-linux) open which might prompt M$ to do something if it gets enough comments/votes.

Comment: There is also [an issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-jdbc/issues/696) posted at the official mssql-jdbc repository on GitHub.

Comment: When I've had this issue it had to do with the user not being assigned to the correct role or having insufficient permission to connect to the specified DB.

Comment: @Kidiskidvogingogin are you suggesting that is possible? Note that I'm not talking about SQL server accounts, but AD accounts.